# Joomla Custom Form Does not Read Correct post value

Tags: php, joomla, article

```
$input =JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$post_array = $input->getArray($_POST);
```

to read the post values in a Joomla Article using sourcerer. This works fine if I run the form the first time - I get the correct values.

The second time i submit the form the post values from the first submit are shown even though the Post Values (which i checked in the Browser ) are different.

Any Ideas on what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling cache should do the trick. It seems that your values in your form are being cached.